# How can i make completetly undetectable program ( a program known)?

Tags: security, memory-editing, cheat-engine

This question is little complex. I want to hide "cheat engine" from some detecter programs.They're checking cheat engine name in running program list,and checking memory for some special strings or data for detect that program. How can i make completely undetectable program (known).

I tried some tricks like "Windows Title Changer".But those detecters are checking memory for detecting.So i should change memory data for that program.But i dont know how can i make do that. Any idea?
Thank you in advance..

Comment: if those programs prevent use of cheat engine, there must be a good reason...

Comment: maybe.but its not cheat like its name. its memory debugger.so all can debug to what they want.this world is one of the free world.they can try to prevent some things for their own interest,but i hope free world will win.ty for your "good" reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal is not to make a program "completely undetected" but rather to just bypass the detection mechanisms that exists in the anti-cheat/anti-debug routines the developer utilized.  The reason is because you cannot make something "completely undetected", it's a cat and mouse game and you only need to stay one step ahead or update when necessary to bypass again once you become detected.

The solution is to reverse engineer the methods of detection, half of this is trial and error and the other half is reversing the assembly instructions that are being executed and figuring out what they do.  This is truly an art form.  You also want to consider learning how cheat engine works as certain techniques it uses such as attaching a debugger and opening a handle to the process can be detected.

To bypass string detection you can open CheatEngine.exe with a hex editor, do a find and replace on the string "Cheat Engine" and replace it with gibberish, don't forget to do unicode as well.  You must also change the folder name as it also includes the offending string.  This detects basic detection of Cheat Engine.  The next step up from there is detection of a debugger by using [IsDebuggerPresent()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx) or by manually checking the debugger flag in the [Process Environment Block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706(v=vs.85).aspx) or PEB.  You can bypass those by patching the function or overwriting the flag in the PEB.

There are near limitless ways to detect unauthorized access to the memory of a process.

Peter Ferrie wrote "The Ultimate Anti Debugging Reference" which is a must read.